# CSV file from command

Tags: regex, bash, csv

I am trying to get CSV file with HDD temperatures separated by ";", here is my command which will be running every hour :

```
sudo hddtemp /dev/sd? /dev/sda? | tr "\n" ";" > file.csv
```

The problem is, that result is in one line and not separated :

```
/dev/sda: HGST HUS728T8TALE6L4: 44°C;/dev/sdb: WDC WD60EDAZ-11U78B0: 37°C;/dev/sdc: ST6000DM003-2CY186: 39°C;/dev/sdd: WDC WD120EDBZ-11B1HA0: 40°C;/dev/sde: WDC WD120EDAZ-11F3RA0: 41°C;/dev/sdf: WDC WD60EDAZ-11U78B0: 37°C;/dev/sdg: WDC WD101FZBX-00ATAA0: 49°C
```

I need to achieve :

```
/dev/sda:; HGST HUS728T8TALE6L4:; 44°C;
/dev/sdb:; WDC WD60EDAZ-11U78B0:; 37°C;
/dev/sdc:; ST6000DM003-2CY186:; 39°C;
/dev/sdd:; WDC WD120EDBZ-11B1HA0:; 40°C;
/dev/sde:; WDC WD120EDAZ-11F3RA0:; 41°C;
/dev/sdf:; WDC WD60EDAZ-11U78B0:; 37°C;
/dev/sdg:; WDC WD101FZBX-00ATAA0:; 49°C;
```

How should I update the command please?

Comment: Please add output of `sudo hddtemp /dev/sd? /dev/sda?` to your question (no comment here).

Answer (score 1):

The `tr` command replaced all the newlines with `;`. If you want to append `;` to the end of each line, use `sed`.

```
sudo hddtemp /dev/sd? /dev/sda? | sed 's/$/;/' > file.csv
```

`$` is a regular expression that matches the end of the line.